# Duplicate markup or position with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form that sits within the header of my site.

On mobile viewports, I want to move the form from my header to half-way up the page (in between content).

Is it better to have duplicate forms to manage, that toggle-hide based on a media query or should I reposition the form with javascript/jQuery on resize.

The downside to the latter seems to be issues with both speed & the potential that a user disables their javascript.

FYI: The site is designed to work mass-market down to IE7 and potentially IE6.

Curious to know your thoughts or if there is an alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not too complicated markup wise (hence the reason I didn't include it). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an adaptive rather than responsive solution?

You can sniff server side for a mobile in php, and output the code from an include file in the right place.  Server side solutions are going to reduce any potential ie6 nightmares, too.

Comment: That is an interesting approach that slipped my mind. The downside is for browser widths that are small on a non mobile device the layout could break. Thanks for you help, appreciated.